# Least constraining value heuristic in Sudoku

Tags: recursion, game-theory, constraint-satisfaction, board-games, sudoku

I was trying to implement Least Constraining Value Heuristic in Sudoku but wasn't getting the idea on how to do it. Can someone share their idea for the same ?

Comment: There’s no need to try so hard. Sudoku is so easy that any heuristic would work.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus True, unless you generalize and go to larger grids than 9x9 designed for humans.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly this heuristic is?

Comment: [The edit in revision 2](https://cs.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/75178) seems to have changed the meaning of the question.  Also it introduces two questions (please post only one question per post) and it's not clear what is meant by either one (more context and elaboration would be needed) so I don't think the question is suitable for re-opening even after this change.  I think it would be better to post a new question rather than changing the meaning of an existing one.